# Calculating mean price by day

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mean

Quite a simple task I guess...
I am trying to calculate the mean price per day. There are 3 different days here and each has some price.
This is the DataFrame I initially have

```
 ID       Date      RoomAv    Price
  1    2001-01-02    TRUE      110
  2    2001-01-04    FALSE     120
  3    2001-01-03    TRUE      130
  4    2001-01-03    TRUE      140
  5    2001-01-03    TRUE      150
  6    2001-01-02    FALSE     160
  7    2001-01-02    TRUE      170
  8    2001-01-04    TRUE      180
  9    2001-01-04    FALSE     190
 10    2001-01-02    TRUE      200
```

I need it to be something like this

```
    Date      AveragePrice
 2001-01-02       num1
 2001-01-03       num2
 2001-01-04       num3
```

This is what I tried to do

```
df <- DataFrame %>%
  group_by(DataFrame$Date) %>%
  summarize(DataFrame$price == mean(DataFrame$Price))
```

and I got:

```
Error: Column `DataFrame$price == mean(DataFrame$Price)` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0
```

Have not used the data.table library but would like to hear how it's possible there.

Comment: You generally don't need to use `dataframe_name$` inside `dplyr`-based functions

Answer (score 4):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Price = mean(Price), by = Date]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

**Using dplyr**

```
df <- DataFrame %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(price == mean(Price))
```

**Using data.table**

```
df <- DataFrame[, mean(Price),.(Date)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate()` from base R to make it:

```
dfout <- aggregate(Price ~Date, df, mean)
```

such that

```
> dfout
        Date    Price
1 2001-01-02 160.0000
2 2001-01-03 140.0000
3 2001-01-04 163.3333
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, Date = c("2001-01-02", "2001-01-04", 
"2001-01-03", "2001-01-03", "2001-01-03", "2001-01-02", "2001-01-02", 
"2001-01-04", "2001-01-04", "2001-01-02"), RoomAv = c(TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), Price = c(110L, 
120L, 130L, 140L, 150L, 160L, 170L, 180L, 190L, 200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in R `==` is used to test if some value is equal to another, as `x == 1`. Thus, you should assign the new variable in summarize with `=`. Here is the correct version.

```
library(dplyr)
DataFrame %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(avrgPrice = mean(Price))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
Actually I found this method as the shortest:

```
dfMean <- aggregate(DataFrame$Price ~ DataFrame$Date, DataFrame, mean)
```